# Finding related XML elements filtering on attribute from current element in XPath

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

How can the following statement best be modified so that I receive a list of Contact.Name with Address.Location (I'd like to use XPath and not subqueries/WHERE-conditions if possible)? I've tried all sorts of syntax at @@@Name but no luck :( - I want to reference the original node there.

```
DECLARE @data AS XML
SELECT @data = '
    <Data>
        <Contact Name="John"/>
        <Contact Name="Bob"/>
        <Address ContactName="John" Location="JohnStreet1"/>
        <Address ContactName="John" Location="JohnStreet2"/>
        <Address ContactName="Bob" Location="BobStreet1"/>
    </Data> 
'

SELECT 
    x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)') [Contact.Name],   
    y.v.value('@Location','VARCHAR(255)') [Address.Location]
FROM 
    @data.nodes('/Data[1]/Contact') AS x(v)
CROSS APPLY
    x.v.nodes('/Data[1]/Address[@ContactName=@@@Name]') AS y(v)
ORDER BY
    x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)')
```

PS. This won't work since the parameter needs to be a literal :(

```
x.v.nodes('/Data[1]/Address[@ContactName=' + x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)') + ']') AS y(v)
```

Please note: Currently I'm doing the following to get the desired resultset (but not in a *clean XPath way*):

```
SELECT 
    x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)') [Contact.Name],   
    y.v.value('@Location','VARCHAR(255)') [Address.Location]
FROM 
    @data.nodes('/Data[1]/Contact') AS x(v)
CROSS APPLY
    x.v.nodes('/Data[1]/Address') AS y(v)
WHERE
    y.v.value('@ContactName','VARCHAR(255)')=x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)')
ORDER BY
    x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a pure XQuery (which also happens to be a pure XPath 2.0 expression):**

```
  for $c in /*/Contact/@Name
    return
      for $loc in /*/Address[@ContactName eq $c]/@Location
           return
              data(($c, $loc, '&#xA;'))
```

**When this XPath expression is evaluated against the provided XML document:**

```
<Data>
    <Contact Name="John"/>
    <Contact Name="Bob"/>
    <Address ContactName="John" Location="JohnStreet1"/>
    <Address ContactName="John" Location="JohnStreet2"/>
    <Address ContactName="Bob" Location="BobStreet1"/>
</Data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
John JohnStreet1
 John JohnStreet2 
 Bob BobStreet1
```

**Do Note**:

This is a pure XQuery / XPath 2.0 solution. I don't know the SQL Server XQuery dialect and hope that you would be able to apply this solution to your case.

Probably something like:

```
select @data.query(
      'for $c in /*/Contact/@Name
        return
          for $loc in /*/Address[@ContactName eq $c]/@Location
               return
                  data(($c, $loc, "&#xA;"))'
                   )
```

**Update**:

As noted in a comment by Mikael Eriksson, SQL Server XQuery doesn't accept "heterogeneous sequences" and raises an error.

**Then this, slightly modified query works**:

```
select @data.query(
      'for $c in /*/Contact/@Name
        return
          for $loc in /*/Address[@ContactName eq $c]/@Location
               return
                  (string($c), string($loc), "&#xA;")'
```

**and produces the above wanted, correct result**.

Comment: In SQL Server is gives an error `XQuery [query()]: Heterogeneous sequences are not allowed: found 'xs:string' and 'attribute(Name,xdt:untypedAtomic)'` but can be fixed by using `data((string($c), string($loc), "&#xA;"))`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, Thanks for noticing this -- in standard XQuery this is a perfectly valid expression and I have verified that the query works and produces the quoted result -- using Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're after?

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT  
        x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)') ContactName,
        @data xmlData
    FROM  
        @data.nodes('/Data[1]/Contact') AS x(v)
)
select 
    ContactName as [Contact.Name], 
    y.v.value('@Location','VARCHAR(255)') as [Address.Location] 
from
    cte
        cross apply
    xmlData.nodes('/Data[1]/Address[@ContactName=sql:column("ContactName")]') AS y(v) 
order by 
    ContactName
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry no, I'm looking for a clean XPath solution. I'm looking for a way where I don't need to get the field out in 'SQL' to test performance, currently I'm using a: "WHERE y.v.value('@ContactName','VARCHAR(255)')=x.v.value('@Name','VARCHAR(255)')". Updating my post.